# Проблемы с файловой системой linux

Tags: linux, файловая-система

В последнее время у меня часто стали происходить ошибки файловой системы, при этом она становится только для чтения. Происходят они в рандомное время, по крайней мере я не заметил, чтобы к проблеме приводило определённое действие. Конечно, мне не трудно всё чинить с помощью fsck, но мне бы хотелось узнать, что в принципе может приводить к подобным проблемам.

Comment: Например умирающий диск.

Comment: Или битая память.

Comment: Или БП недодаёт нормальных токов и всё идёт нахрен. Я бы начал со срочного бэкапа всех важных файлов на другой физический винт.

Comment: 1. smartctl, 2. grep -I drm /var/log/dmesg

Comment: @Hellseher smartctl -a /dev/sda1 вывело это: https://pastebin.com/DVuvGPn7

Comment: @Hellseher /var/log/dmesg нет